# Riemann sum of a zero-one function

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

> Find the Riemann sum $S^*$ for
>   $$V(x) =  \begin{cases} 1 & \text{at all fractions $x = p/q$} \\ 0 & \text{at all other points} \end{cases}$$
>   when $\Delta x = 1/n$ and each $x_k^*$ is the midpoint. This $S^*$ is well-behaved but still $V(x)$ is not Riemann integrable.

We have $S^*=\Delta x\sum_{k=1}^nV(x_k^*)$. Since $\Delta x = 1/n$, $\Delta x$ is a fraction and each midpoint $x_k^*$ is a fraction. Therefore, $V(x_k^*) = 1$ at each midpoint $x_k^*$, and $S^*$ becomes $1/n \times n = 1$. Why is $V(x)$ not Riemann integrable?

Comment: This is known as the Dirichlet function. Every interval will have a lower sum equal to zero since the min of every interval is 0. So the lower sum is not equal to the upper sum and it is not integrable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$V$ is not Riemann integrable because all the Darboux lower sums vanish. As you proved that the upper Darboux sums are all equal to $1$, $ V$ is not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Now I see. The midpoint Riemann sum that I computed stays at $1$, just like the upper sum, and the lower sum stays at $0$. They do not converge to a limit.